# Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.dll in Azure SDK 1.4

Tags: logging, azure

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener in a SDK 1.4 project (WCF WebRole) but the assembly Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.dll that is supposed to contain that class is nowhere to be found. Is this normal? Am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot find any trace (bad pun) of this assembly. I'm scratching my head to try and figure out how to get Trace output into the Compute Emulator Console. The problem with researching diagnostics in Azure is that there is so much outdated information out there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I think you are looking for is the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener. That does the logging for the diagnostics of Windows Azure. That is in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics assembly.

Comment: No Scott, he was indeed looking for the DevelopmentFabricTraceListener. See this post here where a MS person makes reference to it: [possible obsolete diagnotics post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/8fa5a1a4-4a91-496a-8a1c-991aa917a32a/)